# Send mail smtp gmail from address showing the gmail address

Tags: c#, email, gmail, sendmail, document-body

In C# I have a method that sends an email via a gmail account.
When I open the email in microsoft outlook the from address is shown as the gmail address and not the strFromAddress that I use in the headers.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***@gmail.com", "*****");

            var strFromAddress = "no-repl@demuynck-printing.be";
            var strToAddress = "sander@demuynck-media.be";
            var strSubject = "Album: '" + lbltitel.Text + "' bestelling";
            var strBody = "<html><head>";
            // new instance of MailMessage
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            // Sender Address
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(strFromAddress);
            // mailMessage.Headers("Selexion Clix Demuynck <no-reply@demuynck-printing.be>");
           // mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("no-reply@demuynck-printing.be"));

            // Recepient Address
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(strToAddress));
            mailMessage.Headers.Add("Reply-To", "info@demuynck-printing.be");
            // Subject 
            mailMessage.Subject = strSubject;

            // Body
            mailMessage.Body = strBody;

            // format of mail message
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            // new instance of Smtpclient

                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: AFAIK this mail could not be sent. You are asking the gmail SMTP service to send a mail from an address not belonging to gmail to an external address. If I am right this is disallowed on every SMTP servers of the world (except spam servers)

Comment: Side note:  `SmtpClient` is `IDisposable` and should be used like so:  `using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()) { ... }`

Comment: Can be not should be. While it is normally considered good practice to wrap Disposable objects in using statements it is not always the case.  Sometimes you need explicit control on how and when objects are disposed of. - although I agree that in this case a using statement would be wise :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just set the displayname property on the MailAddress like so:

```
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("user@domaina.com","no-reply@domainb.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

GMail will change the 'from' address to the account used to login to the SMTP server, unless the email-address used in 'from' field is verified to belong to the same owner. So, in your gmail preferences, just add and verify this specific from address.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Google is violating the SMTP protocols. There is a detailed article about it here: http://lee-phillips.org/gmailRewriting/

Steve's comment is incorrect; an authenticated sender should be able to set any From: header.